# If $x^2f''(x)+5xf'(x)+4f(x)=0$, $\forall x>0 $ what is $f(x)$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> If $f:(0,+\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a real function and $$x^2f''(x)+5xf'(x)+4f(x)=0 \quad , \forall x>0 $$ and $f(1)=1, f'(1)=-3 $ then $f(x)=?$

I tried many ways to find the antiderivative of the functional equation given but failed. More specifically I concluded that

$(x^2f'(x))'+3(xf(x))'+f(x)=0\quad\forall x>0$

and that

$(x^2f(x))''+(xf(x))'+f(x)=0\quad \forall x>0$

But none of the above was helpful

Comment: Try the substitution $x = e^u$

Comment: This is a Cauchy-Euler equation. A Google search for that will tell you its solution

Comment: I searched what Sean said and it turns out that $f(x)=x^{-2}$ but then $f'(1)$ is not equal to $-3$

Comment: change variable to $x = e^u$, the ODE becomes $$\left(\frac{d}{du} + 2\right)^2 f = 0 \iff e^{-2u}\frac{d^2}{du^2} \left(e^{2u} f\right) = 0
\implies e^{2u}f = Au + B \implies \cdots$$ for suitable chosen constants $A,B$.

Comment: well it seems that the wanted function is $f(x)=\frac{1-lnx}{x^2}$ but I dont know how we reach there using simple antiderivative rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a second-order [Cauchy-Euler equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_equation) since it is in the form:
$$x^2y''+axy'+by=0$$

---

Hence, we can use the standard ansatz $f=x^{\lambda}$ which is as far as I know, the most efficient method. If we evaluate derivatives, we obtain:
$$f'=\lambda x^{\lambda-1}$$
$$f''=\lambda(\lambda-1)x^{\lambda-2}$$
We can now substitute it into your ODE to obtain:
$$(\lambda^2+4\lambda+4)\cdot x^{\lambda}=0$$
Since for all $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$, $x^{\lambda}\neq 0$ if $x\neq 0$, then it remains that we have to solve a quadratic equation for $\lambda$:
$$\lambda^2+4\lambda+4=0 \iff (\lambda+2)^2=0$$
Hence, $\lambda=-2$ is a root of multiplicity $2$.

---

The general solution to a second order Cauchy-Euler equation with a repeated root is given by:
$$f(x)=c_1 x^{\lambda}+c_2 x^{\lambda}\ln{x}$$
Even though this general solution is well known, it is worth knowing that the other linearly independent solution $f_2(x)=x^{\lambda}\ln{x}$ can be derived using [reduction of order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduction_of_order) by using $f_1(x)=x^{\lambda}$. Hence, in your case the general solution will be:
$$f(x)=\frac{c_1+c_2\ln{x}}{x^2}$$
I will leave you to evaluate $c_1$ and $c_2$ using the conditions you are given.

Answer (score 1):

Let $y=\frac z {x^2}$ which makes the equation $$z''+\frac{z'}{x}=0$$ Now, reduce the order $w=z'$ to get $$w'+\frac w x=0$$ which is separable leading to $w=\frac {c_1}x$.

Integrate again to get $z=c_1\log(x)+c_2$.

By the end $$y=\frac{c_1\log(x)+c_2 }{x^2}$$ Now apply the  conditionto get $c_1,c_2$.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

Look for solutions of the form $$f (x)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}a_n(x-1)^n $$

Comment: While this is valid, the usual Cauchy-Euler ansatz is more efficient.